# JSF&primefaces after dialog closed background buttons don't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a button to open a dialog:

```
<p:commandButton id="addbutton" value="Новая контрольная точка" oncomplete="dlg_add.show();" rendered="#{controlPointBean.selectedSubject != null}"/>
```

And a dialog with wizard in it:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg_add">
<p:wizard id="wizard" widgetVar="wizard">
    <p:tab title="Тип контрольной точки">
        <p:dataTable id="cptypes" var="cptype" value="#{controlPointBean.cptypesList}" rows="10" rowKey="#{cptype.ID}"
         selection="#{controlPointBean.selectedCPType}" selectionMode="single" filteredValue="#{controlPointBean.filteredCPtypesList}">  
            <p:column headerText="Тип контрольной точки" filterBy="type" filterMatchMode="contains">  
                #{cptype.type}  
            </p:column> 
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Общее">
        <h:panelGrid id="data" columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Название: " /> 
            <p:inputText value="#{controlPointBean.name}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Модуль: " /> 
            <p:inputText value="#{controlPointBean.module}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Минимальный балл: " /> 
            <p:inputText value="#{controlPointBean.minGrade}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Максимальный балл: " /> 
            <p:inputText value="#{controlPointBean.maxGrade}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Завершить">
        <p:panel header="Проверьте введённые данные">              
            <h:panelGrid id="confirmation" columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Предмет:"/>
                <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{controlPointBean.selectedSubject.name}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Тип:"/>
                <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{controlPointBean.selectedCPType.type}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Название: " /> 
                <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{controlPointBean.name}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Модуль: " /> 
                <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{controlPointBean.module}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Минимальный балл: " /> 
                <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{controlPointBean.minGrade}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Максимальный балл: " /> 
                <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{controlPointBean.maxGrade}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>

        <p:commandButton value="Принять" update=":form:messages, :form:DataTable" actionListener="#{controlPointBean.save}" oncomplete="dlg_add.hide();wizard.reset();"/>               
    </p:tab>
</p:wizard>
```

When wizard is completed and I click "Принять" button, dialog closes, updates everything, but buttons that was on a background of dialog just don't do anything until the page is reloaded. In primefaces debug console it looks like they are not clicked.
Here is the method save() from backing bean:

```
public void save() throws SystemException{
    try{            
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();        

        ControlPointLocalServiceUtil.addControlPoint(name, selectedSubject.getID(), selectedCPType.getID(),
                module, minGrade, maxGrade, 0, PortalUtil.getUserId(portletRequest));
    }
    catch(RowAlreadyExistsException e){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
            "Ошибка", e.getLocalizedMessage()));                        
    }
    finally{
        selectedCPType=null;name=null;module=0;minGrade=0;maxGrade=0;
        cpList= ControlPointLocalServiceUtil.findAll();
        filterCPBySelectedSubject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors? The symptoms sound like it.

Comment: Maybe it is this issue? http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm

Comment: Yep, it was JS error.
deleted wizard.reset(); from oncomplete tag and it works fine.
But now wizard doesn't start from the beginning when I click the button.

Comment: @user2851836 - How? Please post an answer